Linear discriminant analysis and PDF
I'm going through LDA material. I'm not 100% sure how to interprete the PDF of two samples in the context of LDA.
Suppose this situation:

For one thing, why is the shape of the pink PDF on the right more narrow? The prior is higher but that has nothing to do with the shape of the PDF. I thought variance makes it more or less narrow.
Two, why has the decision boundary shifted to the left in the right picture? Is it because the prior is higher for the pink (meaning there is more pink in the population)?
Thanks in advance.
Here is the video for the diagram in case any colleague or myself in the future want to consult this information. :)
